# Restoring a Windows partition image from Mac (Boot Camp) to a PC

Tags: windows, restore, boot-camp

I'm running Windows XP SP3 on my Mac using Boot Camp.

Objective: I'd like to move this partition to a PC.

This is what I tried:

1. Create image using WinClone
2. Restore image to a partition on the PC using Paragon
3. Reboot from new partition

Result: it attempts to boot Windows XP (Windows flag and progress bar loading screen) but then gives me the old BSOD. Safe mode just hangs while loading.

(I then uninstalled KB977165 on a hunch, but that did nothing to help the issue.)

Any ideas, advice, etc would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apparently jpwagner also posted this question on stackoverflow and it was also migrated here. Here is a link to the other migrated dup: http://superuser.com/questions/146826/restoring-mac-bootcamp-windows-partition-image-to-windows-machine

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly you moved/copied your Boot Camp partition from your Intel Mac to a non-Mac PC and then expected it to just boot?? Why would you expect this to work? There are probably lots of low level components which are different between the two systems.

What I would do when I wanted to move a Windows XP partition from one machine to another would be to do a [Windows repair install of XP](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/helpandsupport/learnmore/tips/doug92.mspx) to the partition I copied over. This should preserve all your settings and application installs but still install the correct drivers Windows needs to properly run on the hardware you moved the partition to.

As outlined in the link above, a repair install takes the same steps as a regular XP install until after you press F8 to agree to the license agreement. At this point the install should search for existing Windows installations and find the one which you copied over from your Mac. You should be given the option to highlight that partition and press R to repair Windows XP in that partition.

If you do **not** see the partition you copied over listed as a previous Windows installation do not go any further until you fix this. (You don't want to do a clean install and destroy your previous setup).

My recollection is that if the boot.ini file in the copied partition did not match the partition structure on the new system, then the install process would not recognize that partition as an existing Windows installation. Correcting the entry in the boot.ini with a text editor would usually fix this.

Make sure the install disc you use is at least Win XP SP2 or SP3. (Slipstream the service packs and create your own install CD if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install the storage controller drivers for your new machine, or sysprep your existing maching before you take the image.